# DPM 2012 Self Service Recovery tool

Tags: backup, scdpm

Trying to get DPM Self Service Recovery tool to work.  i've installed the SSRT on client computer, but when i try to connect to the DPM Server i get an error ID:33107

`Connection refused by DPM Server server.domain. your user account is not configured as an authorized end user on the server.`

If anyone has successfully overcome this, I could use some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open DPM 2012 console,  under recovery select at the top left end user recovery.  then go through and fill out the steps and once your done adding a user role, you should be able to connect from another computer.  make sure the user is part of the sql group.